# How can I play audio file from NSLibraryDirectory from Urban Airship?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, urbanairship.com, audio-player

I am using Urban Airship to manage In-App purchases of non-consumable audio files.  UA stores the files in the Library Directory and I want to simply have a specific file play when the user pushes a button.  I have been playing with the recommended code below but can't seem to figure it out.  Can anyone provide more details on how to play and audio file from the directory?

```
NSString *productId = @"YOUR PRODUCT ID";
NSString *filename = @"YOUR FILE NAME";

NSString* libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
// build the fill paths by appending ua and downloads to the base libraryPath
libraryPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ua"];
libraryPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloads"];
// Append the product id:
NSString *downloadDirectory = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:productId];
// now append your filename
NSString *fullPathToMyFile = self.filePath = [downloadDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
```

- Notes:
- productid I assume is com.company.application.product
- file name I assume is the name of the file once it has been unzipped (the name of the file uploaded to UA)
  -The rest seems to build the location for the file but I get a "Property 'filepath' not found" error.  Where should I define 'filepath'?
- I was thinking of just playing it with a play method:

```
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPathToMyFile error:nil]];
[player play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the path to the file, and even if it exists.
You can see all file pass when it do NSLog to it.

```
NSLog(@"fullPathToMyFile = %@",fullPathToMyFile);
```

If you work with simulator you can go to folder when your file located.